# Use formula as a string

Tags: vba, excel, paramarray

I one cell I have to use several different formula depending on certains case.
I another sheet named Static, I wrote a Matrix of formulas in TEXT for all the cases.
My matrix have Criteria1 in rows Criteria2  in columns
So with INDEX/MATCH i will get the text formula for every scenario Criteria1/Criteria2.

Now I want to Evaluate this formula in text.
I did a custom function in VBA

```
Function Evalue(ByVal str As String)
Application.Volatile
Evalue = Evaluate(str)
End Function
```

It works when the function is in one block like `SUM` `CONCATENATE` etc... but not when there operation of function + -

Answer (score 0):

Your UDF works for me........in A1 enter the text string:

sum(B2:B5)+sum(C4:C9)

in another cell:

=Evalue(A1)  displays the correct value.